# Calculate the value in onload using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using 3 fields like

```
<input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter quantity" id="quantity" />
  <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Enter price" id="price" />
  <input type="text" name="total" placeholder="Enter Total" id="total" />
```

I need the answer like total = quantity * price;After enter price it's automatically load the value in total field.for example quantity = 1,price = 100.I need total = 100.How to write in jquery

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. SO is for fixing broken code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var calculateChange = function() {
  var qty = parseFloat($('#quantity').val());
  var pri = parseFloat($('#price').val());
  var total = qty * pri;

  if (!isNaN(total)) { 
    $('#total').val(total);
    var handamount = parseFloat($('#handamount').val()) - total;
    alert(handamount);
    $('#handamount').val(handamount);
  }
}

$('#quantity').on('change', calculateChange);
$('#price').on('change', calculateChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter quantity" id="quantity" />
<input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Enter price" id="price" />
<input type="text" name="total" placeholder="Enter Total" id="total" />
<input type="text" name="handamount" id="handamount" value="50" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I got the answer

Comment: Sir i need one clarification in coding.ie In that same manner i need to calucate another field that is amount.So i have to reduce the (amount - total) value.Intially i have 50 in amount after enter price i need amount field also update.

Comment: qty = 1;pri=1;tot=1;amount=amount-tot;

Comment: I use the below coding.Kindly check the coding.I got the value of amount,but it's not updated in that field

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  var calculateChange = function() {
  var qty = parseFloat($('#quantity').val());
  var pri = parseFloat($('#price').val());
  var total = qty * pri;
  $('#total').val(total);
  var handamount = parseFloat($('#handamount').val()) - total;
  alert(handamount);
  $('#handamount').val(handamount);
}

$('#quantity').on('change', calculateChange);
$('#price').on('change', calculateChange);
$('#total').on('change',calculateChange);

</script>

Comment: <input type="text" name="handamount"  id="handamount" value = <?php echo $handamount; ?> class="form-control"/>

Comment: @Nisha.A I modified my answer so that the handamount works too. I see a problem with your input, it might need to be `<input type="text" name="handamount" id="handamount" value="<?php echo $handamount; ?>" class="form-control"/>`

Comment: Thank you so much @Jaime Rodas.I got the answer.

Comment: Use these same format can i subtract 2 more fileds?This is my code,Kindly check the code,and reply me

Comment: if (!isNaN(handamount)) {
     //alert(handamount);
    var  handamount = parseFloat($('#handamount').val()) - tea;
   $('#handamount').val(handamount);
   }
   if (!isNaN(handamount)) {
     //alert(handamount);
   var  handamount = parseFloat($('#handamount').val()) - petrol;
   $('#handamount').val(handamount);
   }

Comment: $('#tea').on('change',calculateChange);
$('#petrol').on('change',calculateChange);

Comment: After your code i just add the above code,is this correct format.when i enter tea amount again it have to reduce,like that petrol.First handamount-total ,then handamount - tea,then handamount-petrol.Kindly check the code and reply me

Comment: Sorry to disturb you.I got the answer.I used different function.Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this for a start:

```
$('#price').keyup(function() {
    $('#total').val($('#quantity').val() * $(this).val());
});
```

I think you might like to use some checks within it, but thats up to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

use the following function to calculate the value.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter quantity" id="quantity" />
  <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Enter price" id="price" onkeyup="func();"  />
  <input type="text" name="total" placeholder="Enter Total" id="total" />
<script>
function func() {

        var a = parseInt($('input[name=quantity]').val());
        var b = parseInt($('input[name=price]').val());
        if(b!="") {
           var total = a*b;
            $('#total').val(total);
        }

}
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <input type="text" name="quantity" placeholder="Enter quantity" id="quantity" />
  <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="Enter price" id="price" />
  <input type="text" name="total" placeholder="Enter Total" id="total" onkeyup="func();" />

Comment: i tried ur code.but value on cme after type price,total not come

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: func is not defined.This error come

Comment: how to write in on focus